# How do I center forms in a fluid layout?

Tags: html, css

If I have a div with %-based width. And in this div I got 1 row with 2 forms, and 1 row with 1 form. How can I center the forms in the div (both rows)?

Example code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input />
    <input />
    <br />
    <input />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:70%;
    background:red;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nc4L4bc5/

Comment: you forgot to post your fiddle link. Your above link is just point to the jsfiddle site.

Comment: My bad! Will edit the post now, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/nc4L4bc5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the `.container`. Keeps it centered during expansion and shrinking.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input />
  <input />
  <br />
  <input />
</div>
```